# VSCode: How do I set keyboard shortcut for Show All Opened Editors in Quick Open (edt command)

Tags: visual-studio-code

`cmd+p` (`ctrl+p` on windows) searches files in current project and if I want to search currently opened files I can do `cmd+p` and then type `edt` (one of the commands they show you when you press `?` to list available commands)

[vscode available commands from command palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0ePk.png)

Is there a way to create a keyboard shortcut to open the command palette with `edt` pre-filled? Just like open symbols with `@` pre-filled. In Sublime I can write `"args": {"text": "@"}` in the setting json file but I can't find anything similar in VSCode, any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Never mind, I only found out this command in default keybindings after I've made this post...

`{ "key": "alt+cmd+tab",           "command": "workbench.action.showAllEditors" },`

Comment: On Windows with VSCode version: 1.33.1, it was `Ctrl + P` for me.

Answer (score 36):

In vscode version 1.30.2
You can go to menu `File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts`
And go to `Show All Editors`
The default is: `Ctrl + K` `Ctrl + P`

Comment: This question's solution should be changed to this answer. It's more helpful/relevant.